# Trying to install Mumble on CentOS

Tags: centos, installation

I am trying to install mumble on my CentOS VPS following these directions:

```
http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/install-the-mumble-voip-server-to-redhat-or-centos
```

When I get to this line:

```
rpm2cpio mumble-server-1.2.2-3mdv2011.0.x86_64.rpm > file.lzma
lzma -d file.lzma
```

I am getting this error:

```
root@vps-1112788-12524 [/home/~~~~/mumble]# rpm2cpio mumble-1.2.4-0.20120422.1-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm > file.lzma
root@vps-1112788-12524 [/home/~~~~/mumble]# lzma -d file.lzma
lzma: file.lzma: File format not recognized
```

I did update the name of the file since the link they gave me was not available. I got the new rpm from the same place:

```
http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mumble+server&submit=Search+...
```

I'm new to Linux so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm new to Linux so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Fixed that for you. It is not advisable to install old-school Unix tar.gz whatever packages on RedHat and its derivatives (for that matter, on most package-based distributions), since the probability of messing up files beyond redemption is very high.

With this in mind, I recommend doing several things that may ease your burden.

First, as root `yum install rpm-build rpmrebuild rpmlint ruby ruby-devel`. This will set up the environment for a real time-saving utility, `fpm`. Next, install fpm (as root): `gem install fpm`

Now you have a real treat: an almost automatic RPM building environment. 
Download the RPM for Mandriva from rpmfind site (mentioned in the tutorial you linked to), and extract (with cpio - that's where you snagged - please read the `man cpio` page, or file-roller) the scripts to be run after installation, compare them with instructions posted in your tutorial and have them handy for later.

Now, download and rebuild the whole mumble-server source .tar.gz archive, checking it for integrity if checksums/digests are provided:

```
  tar xzvf mumble-server*.tar.gz
  cd ./mumble-server*
  .configure --prefix=/usr
  make
  mkdir -p /tmp/mumble-server
  make install DESTDIR=/tmp/mumble-server
  fpm -s dir -t rpm -n mumble-server -C /tmp/mumble-server -p mumble-server-VERSION_ARCH.rpm usr
  export EDITOR=emacs
  rpmrebuild -e -n -d . -p mumble-server-VERSION_ARCH.rpm
```

This will build the package and call Emacs for you to customize the RPM .spec file and include the snippets you gleaned from Mandriva's RPM and tutorials. After you've done that, save changes and exit Emacs, press `y` to rebuild the package with new settings. After rebuilding it will be placed into the ARCH subdirectory, from where you can issue `yum install mumble-server*.rpm` to put things right. THE HUGE ADVANTAGE of RPMs is the ability to uninstall if things go awry.

Last thing, but probably the most important: DO NOT TRUST BLINDLY COUNSELS OF STRANGERS (including me, *especially* me!). Read `man` and `info` pages yourself, take whatever is written on the web with a grain of salt and try to understand exactly what and why you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your immediate problem of extracting the RPM archive I would recommend using cpio as follows

```
# rpm2cpio mumble-1.2.4-0.20120422.1-mdv2012.0.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

this will extract all the files into the current directory. Note that they will be in their respective sub-directories i.e. if you extracted to */var/tmp* the binaries will be in */var/tmp/usr/bin*. However there are no guarantees the program will run on an unsupported distro.